Where located MAUI iOS *.app builded with VS on Windows
Im use Visual Studio for create Android/iOS application. Need a check correct copying files to Resource/ Assets/ etc. inside "App Bundle", but i cant found builded iOS *.app location.
For Android path to application located here:
...\bin\Debug\net8.0-android\<id>.apk

For iOS im check my remote connected to VS Mac folders, but iOS *.app is not found:

XCode DerivedData/
Library/Cache/Xamarin

Where i can found iOS *.app builded with VS on Windows?

can you provide build log? It should  be generally found in Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/<your_project_name>/<random_hash>/bin//net8.0-ios/<your_app_name>.app

mtbs directory is not avaliable in Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs

What are you trying to do? Can't you just use the Publish functionality and inspect the .ipa file? You'll have to rename the .ipa file to .zip to inspect it.

@Anonimys may be it's hidden . Use Shift + Command + . to view hidden files... I dont know how this goes form windows keyboard

@Julian Yes, this is one of the possible solutions. But why take extra steps if the *.app should be located somewhere locally before installing it on a real device

@BhavaneshN on Windows no one hide elements in bin/ obj/ folders

@Anonimys Just trying to help find a viable solution, in case the file is inaccessible. I've never looked for the debug versions of the app archive before. I'm more curious about what ends up in the production version.

@Anonimys Whaaaat??? im not talking about windows .... you wont find anything related to iOS build in windows system.. above mentioned path is  for your Mac system

@Anonimys I may be wrong but file extension for iOS application is not *.app, you should look for *.ipa file.

@Rafael *.ipa its compressed file include *.app for deploy to App Store,
*.app - its a main Application Bundle

@Anonimys read my answer, if you have any question, ask.

To answer the question:
The way you see where the built IOS application is - right click on your project file > view archives > Select + open folder.
(The usual path will be AppData > Local > Xamarin > iOS > Archives for the user that built the app)
However,
Your mentioning "debug" , "bin/obj", "installing it on a real device", makes me doubt that you actually prepared such archive.
The way hot reload works has nothing to do with actually building application on MAC. And you wont find what you are are looking for, because it is simply not there.
